# Comparing 2 lists of dictionaries and adding a key,value when a common key is identified

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries. The first list will contain significantly more dictionaries than the second list. There could be up to 200-300 dictionaries in list1 and no more than 10-15 dictionaries in list2.

For example, any dictionary in list1 that has the same `'g': h` key/value as that of list2 needs to add key/value `'j': k` to list 1.

```
list1 = [{'a': b, 'c': d, 'e': f, 'g': h}, 
         {'a': b, 'c': d, 'e': f, 'g': h}, 
         {'a': b, 'c': d, 'e': f, 'g': h}, 
         {'a': b, 'c': d, 'e': f, 'g': h}
         ]

list2 = [{'g': h, 'j': k}]
```

I'm struggling on finding any previous examples of this type and cannot figure out a function of my own.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial implementation could be:

```
for d1 in list1:
    for d2 in list2:
        if any(pair in d1.items() for pair in d2.items()):
            d1.update(d2)
```

The value of `list1` after this transformation:

```
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'j': 'k'},
 {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'j': 'k'},
 {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'j': 'k'},
 {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'j': 'k'}]
```